# Firebase data gets overwritten

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Every time my location changes i want it to add an waypoint to the same root id, but every time it just overwrites the waypoint inside the root.
Have changed .setValue to .updateChildren but still no luck.

```
Firebase mainRef = null;
private void saveToFirebase() {

    while (isFirstTime) {
        // Generates root id
        mainRef = myFirebaseRef.push();
        isFirstTime = false;
    }


    // Generates new id for waypoint
    Firebase wayRef1 = mainRef.push();
    String waypointKey = wayRef1.getKey();


    // Create waypoint post
    Map<String, Object> newPost = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    newPost.put("latitude", mLastLocation.getLatitude());
    newPost.put("longitude", mLastLocation.getLongitude());


    // POST HOLDER
    Map<String, Object> waypointHolder = new HashMap<>();
    waypointHolder.put(waypointKey, newPost);


    // PARENT OF WAYPOINTHOLDER
    Map mParent = new HashMap();
    mParent.put("timeStamp", mLastUpdateTime);
    mParent.put("waypoints", waypointHolder);
    mainRef.updateChildren(mParent);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a hashmap of waypoint values, but you don't load the existing values into the hashmap before adding a new one. Therefore you are creating a new hashmap each time, adding an entry to it, and then posting it to firebase. This results in a hashmap with one waypoint entry each time being stored in firebase.

Comment: Woops, Thanks for the help!